# Why can't developers lose admin rights and use virtual machines?

Tags: visual-studio, vmware

Company A is trying to remove local admin rights from developers and get them to use virtual machines on VMWare.  Mainly MS web development Visual Studio, Biztalk, IIS etc

The argument is that local admin rights on a vmware installation is just as good. Is there a killer justification for developers need local admin rights?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about business policy and practices

Comment: Apologies.  Its supposed to be a question about the ability of developers to do their job when working with certain technical constraints.